# Stuck with an unknow column error but the column that exist propel symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony, propel, schema.yml

Bonjour,

I am working on symfony 1.4 with propel orm.
I am having this error : `500 | Internal Server Error | PropelException
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'my_app_language_i18n.LIBELLE' in 'order clause']`
My is that dont know how to solve this. The column exist in the database with the same name.
Symfony use a schema.yml file to do the link between entities and tables of the database.

```
 my_app_language_i18n:
_attributes: { phpName: MyAppLanguageI18n }
id: { phpName: Id, type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, required: true, foreignTable: my_app_language, foreignReference: id, onDelete: CASCADE, onUpdate: CASCADE }
culture: { phpName: Culture, type: VARCHAR, size: '7', primaryKey: true, required: true }
libelle: { phpName: Libelle, type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true }
```

i did not change something on this table/entity i was not working on it i dont know why and where this error came.
I tried to rebuild the schema.yml but error is still here.
If anyone has encontred this type of error..
Thank you for your help.

Comment: is different in case (upper/lower) have you migrated or upgraded the system?

Comment: it is normal symfony convert to upper case in its classes its a normal behaviour. I have updated my debian system to debian 7 but it was working after the installation.